# What is "worried" part of speech in "I'm worried about something"

Tags: grammar

First, I think the part of speech is"verb",but it is passive.then, I think it is"noun",but the sentence can't use "worried",should use "worry".

Answer (score 1):

In this case, **worried** is an adjective (in other words anxious or troubled, see: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worried).

It cannot be verb in passive, because it wouldn't make sense - it is the person (I) who is worried about something/someone else, so the pronoun I is an agent of the verb.

You can use worry as a verb in passive, for example, *"a lamb was worried by a wolf."*, as someone suggested here. However, the meaning of worry in this context is different, it means hunted, chased, attacked. There are more very different meanings of worry as a verb (see: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/worry)

I don't think you can use **worry about** in passive with the meaning to feel anxious or troubled. It is not possible to find these examples even in the dictionaries. I thought about an example: *"He is constantly worried about by his parents."* (active voice: His parents are constantly worried about him)  but it doesn't sound natural.